# Remove mask after lost focus IG:WebMaskEditor (Infragistics)

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

I have a `IG:WebMaskEditor` for a phone number input field. I am trying to display the phone number masked ONLY when the user enters the number in the WebMaskEditor, example: `(305) 123-4444`. I also want to make sure the mask is removed after the focus has been lost for the webMaskEditor example: `3051234444`. It is currently only removing the mask when the webMaskEdior is empty but not when it contains number and loses focus.

Here's how  I currently have it set up:

```
<ig:WebMaskEditor ID="maskHomePhone" runat="server" InputMask="(000) 000-0000" style="margin-bottom: 0px" Width="85px" CssClass="textEntry" Font-Size="Small" ValidationGroup="1" DisplayMode="BlankWhenEmpty">
                                            </ig:WebMaskEditor>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is the default behavior of the mask control.

This is why you can use the following approach to achieve the mentioned functionality:

- Handle Mask Editor Blur and Focus Client-Side events:

  ```
  <ig:WebMaskEditor ID="WebMaskEditor1" runat="server" InputMask="(000) 000-0000">
      <ClientEvents Blur="WebMaskEditor1_Blur" Focus="WebMaskEditor1_Focus" />
  </ig:WebMaskEditor>
  ```
- In these events modify the mask like follows:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" id="igClientScript">

  function WebMaskEditor1_Blur(sender, eventArgs) {

     sender._setMask("0000000000");
  }

  function WebMaskEditor1_Focus(sender, eventArgs) {

     sender._setMask("(000) 000-0000");
  }

  </script>
  ```

This will allow you to have input mask when control is focused and plain text when control is blured.

Let me know if this approach works in your application.